# How to save choices value in django ？

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I am donig with a poll system for my class. I use `model-form` and `create-view` to serve the poll form. I use `choices` in in the field but I just find out that `create-view` only save the last value of the checkboxes and I want to save all the selected choices as a list maybe. I've tried to change the `form_valid()` method, but I just find out that I need to iterate all the fields to check wheather there are multipule choices. It's not flexible. And I can't figure out other solutions...

How can I meet this requirement? I am truly a newbie..

Thanks in advance.

Thank the friend below for replying in such a short interval after I raised my question. Here is my code.

`models.py`

```
CHOICES = (('m','Math'),('f','French'),('s','Science'),('l','literature'))
class Poll(models.Model):
     [...]
     subject = models.CharField(max_length = 5,choices = CHOICES, blank=True)
     [...]`
```

`forms.py`

```
class PollForm(forms.ModelForm):
     model = Poll
     fields = [..., 'subject', ...]
     widgets = {'subject':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

`views.py`

```
class PollView(CreateView):
     form_class = PollForm
     template_name = 'poll.html'
```

Students can choose subjects they want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to convert your model. If you could provide a sample of the structure that you are using it would be helpful. Still lets try solving your query. First you need identify that choices is nothing more than a many to many field. Saving it in the db should be a bit easier that way. Lets try taking an example with choices for a user:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
  description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, unique=True, verbose_name='profile_user')
  choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choices)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Now if you want to make a default form you could simply do something like:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
  Meta:
    model = UserProfile
```

Now comes your main view. This can be editted and rendered to whatever your use case demands it to be:

```
if request.method=='POST':
  form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    profile = form.save(commit=False)
    profile.user = request.user
    #Implement this as a pre-save so that you can add additional value
    profile.save()
else:
  form = ProfileForm()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to here that this helped you out. Could you mark the answer as well so that others who face the same problem can use the same logic? Thanks